# SDL_TTF system font

Tags: c++, cross-platform, system-font, sdl-ttf

Is there any way to use the default system font with SDL_TFF, without writing platform-specific code? Currently I just use one of the [GNU FreeFont's](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/), but I would like to be able to use the default system font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what is "default system font"? I think all modern OSes allow users to customise fonts, so you need to query it somehow, if you want to use exactly that. If you don't want to write platform-specific code and want to avoid non-portable assumptions, then providing your own fonts is a correct thing to do.

Comment: Default font means something like API call "getSystemDefaultFont". I wondered about it too because I want my app in one file, not using external font file.